# How to use the <slot> element twice?

Tags: javascript, slot, svelte

I'm using Svelte, and I want to create a component that will allow me to do something like this:

```
<CodeDisplay>
    <button class="btn">Button</button>
</CodeDisplay>
```

CodeDisplay.html should look something like this:

```
<slot></slot>
<code><slot></slot></code>
```

Essentially, what I want is a component that will first render the HTML code that I place within the component, and then I want to display the code itself. (I'm building a documentation system.)

Seems to be like you can't use `<slot></slot>` more than once which makes sense.

How would I accomplish what I'm trying here. I really want to avoid duplicating the HTML code twice in my code for every example in the documentation. I just thought it would be nice to have a component that in general, I can pass some HTML, and then the component will render the HTML and show the code.

EDIT:
I just realized I could do something like this:

```
{{{html}}}
<pre><code>{{html}}</code></pre>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        html: '',
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

And display it like this:

```
<CodeDisplay html='<button class="btn">Button</button>'/>
```

But I'm getting some errors with this (that happen inconsistently).

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen named `<slot>`s?

```
<slot name="slot-one"></slot> // Show rendered HTML
<slot name="slot-two"></slot> // Show HTML as string
```

---

When you create your HTML-snippet example with backticks, you can render it in `slot-one` and display it as a (nicely formatted multi-line) example in `slot-two`:

```
let mySnippet = `<div>
                    <div>
                        <span>Hello</span>
                    </div>
                </div`;
```

---

I'm not a SvelteJS expert, but you [you can test/check here with this example](https://svelte.technology/repl?version=1.58.0&data=eyJnaXN0IjpudWxsLCJjb21wb25lbnRzIjpbeyJuYW1lIjoiQXBwIiwic291cmNlIjoiPENvbnRhY3RDYXJkPlxuXHQ8c3BhbiBzbG90PSduYW1lJz5QLiBTaGVybWFuPC9zcGFuPlxuXHQ8c3BhbiBzbG90PSdhZGRyZXNzJz40MiBXYWxsYWJ5IFdheSwgU3lkbmV5PC9zcGFuPlxuPC9Db250YWN0Q2FyZD5cblxuPHNjcmlwdD5cblx0aW1wb3J0IENvbnRhY3RDYXJkIGZyb20gJy4vQ29udGFjdENhcmQuaHRtbCc7XG5cblx0ZXhwb3J0IGRlZmF1bHQge1xuXHRcdGNvbXBvbmVudHM6IHsgQ29udGFjdENhcmQgfVxuXHR9O1xuPC9zY3JpcHQ%2BXG4ifSx7Im5hbWUiOiJDb250YWN0Q2FyZCIsInNvdXJjZSI6IjxkaXYgY2xhc3M9J2NvbnRhY3QtY2FyZCc%2BXG5cdDxoMj48c2xvdCBuYW1lPSduYW1lJz48L3Nsb3Q%2BPC9oMj5cblx0PHNsb3QgbmFtZT0nYWRkcmVzcyc%2BVW5rbm93biBhZGRyZXNzPC9zbG90PlxuXHQ8YnI%2BXG5cdDxzbG90IG5hbWU9J2VtYWlsJz5Vbmtub3duIGVtYWlsPC9zbG90PlxuPC9kaXY%2BXG5cbjxzdHlsZT5cblx0LmNvbnRhY3QtY2FyZCB7XG5cdFx0Ym9yZGVyOiAycHggc29saWQgYmxhY2s7XG5cdFx0cGFkZGluZzogMC41ZW07XG5cdH1cbjwvc3R5bGU%2BXG4ifV0sImRhdGEiOnt9fQ%3D%3D).

Comment: I did read that section in the docs. I don't believe that accomplishes what I'm trying to do.

Comment: So I saw your edit, and that brings to my latest idea on how I can accomplish what I want. Basically, have a JSON file that stores the HTML markup using template strings with backticks like you said.
Then, I can loop through the JSON in my template code and pass in a binding instead of a <slot></slot>. This way my CodeDisplay component can have look more like: {{html}}<code>{{html}}</code>

Comment: Again, I should reiterate that what I would like is to only have to write the HTML once, and the component would then be responsible for rendering the HTML and the HTML code itself.

Comment: It's always a goo idea to store data in a JSON, and use components to display a block of content (keeps your code clean and readable). I haven't really used SvelteJS myself, I just knew about the name slots, since a lot of Js frameworks got those (or something similar). I can't really help you any further, but I hope I've pointed you in the right direction with the named slots and the backticked HTML.

Comment: I've edited my question to include an alternative way for me to accomplish what I want. Difference between two curly braces and three. ({{ vs {{{)

Comment: Would have been nicer to use the slot method though, because putting HTML as a binding doesn't look nice.